# Java - Icon/image is grey on a disabled JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

I'm making minesweeper for a school project. When the player wins or loses, the mines are revealed. Their buttons are disabled, and icons of flags/mines will appear. The problem is that the icons turn grey when the buttons are disabled. Is there a way around this?

I have also tried setting the text of the `JButton` to something like `"<html><img src=\"res\\mine.png\"/></html>"` but it showed some weird image.

Update:
I tried using `setDisabledIcon()` but nothing's showing up. Here's some pseudo-code

The buttons I use for the minefield is a class called `Field`, which extends `JButton`

```
mouseReleased(mouseEvent e) {
    Field fieldClicked = (Field)e.getSource();

    if fieldClicked is mine {
        fieldClicked.setEnabled(false);
        gameTimer.stop();
        setLost(true);

        loop through 2D array of fields {
            if field is a mine {
                field.setDisabledIcon(Field.mineIcon);// public static final icon of Field. mineIcon = new ImageIcon("res\\mine.png")
                field.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured this out in a test

For some reason

```
clickedButton.setDisabledIcon(mineIcon)
```

Alone doesn't do anything.

But:

```
clickedButton.setIcon(mineIcon)
clickedButton.setDisabledIcon(mineIcon)
```

Will show whatever icon I wanted

Answer (score 4):

> a JButton actually allows seven associated images: the main image (use
>   setIcon to specify it if not supplied in the constructor), the image
>   to use when the button is pressed (setPressedIcon), the image to use
>   when the mouse is over it (setRolloverIcon, but you need to call
>   setRolloverEnabled(true) first), the image to use when the button is
>   selected and enabled (setSelectedIcon), **the image to use when the
>   button is disabled (setDisabledIcon)**, the image to use when it is
>   selected but disabled (setDisabledSelectedIcon), and the image to use
>   when the mouse is over it while it is selected
>   (setRolloverSelectedIcon).
>   - http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JButton.html

so use setDisabledIcon(ImageIcon)

Answer (score 2):

The greyed image is the automatically generated one, in case you want a different icon, use [setDisabledIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisabledIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)

```
Icon disabledIcon = new ImageIcon("youricon.gif");
button.setDisabledIcon(disabledIcon);
```

Comment: @AlexYan You might be doing something wrong :) can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or your code?

Comment: I posted some code. The actual code is very long, and is divided into a few files

Comment: @AlexYan 'some code' is not an SSCCE, and is unlikely to be looked at closely (I generally won't spend *any* time looking at code snippets).

Comment: Ah, this is interesting, because I came looking for a way to grey icons out, because what I found was that my jet black icons are black even when the button is disabled. I'm going to be using setDisabledIcon() to explicitly set what I feel should be the default behaviour. :/